# Transforming encoding string to bytes and then writing PDF file not working - What kind of encoding is this?

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, unicode, utf

EDIT: This is solved. Thank you Jeremy Lakeman for your comment, it put me on the right track.

I have a PDF file content string that I am trying to use to produce a PDF file.

EDIT: The encoded string looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pc4X.png) or google doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I4UtmAIDYRTvCjd7005jnfP0GTOAauiF0hRGB3K6w1s/edit?usp=sharing

Part of the problem is certainly that I have not dealt with any encoding so far in my experience, so please forgive me for that.

I'm trying to handle the conversion and writing of the file like this:

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(FileContentString);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
```

This does produce a PDF file, but when I try to open it, Edge PDF Viewer says, "We can't open this file."

In addition to Unicode, I've tried handling the string as UTF-8 and UTF-32 with varied results. All of these options do write the file, but the file either does not open or displays a blank page instead.

Do you know what kind of encoding this is? I sure don't. Or, am I just handling this wrong in general?

Comment: The picture doesn't exist.

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` <-- Microsoft misnamed this class, it should be named `Utf16LEEncoding`.

Comment: What is `FileContentString`, exactly? Where did it come from? How was it created? If it really is a `String` value then your code is entirely incorrect because as `String` values cannot represent binary data it **won't** actually contain a binary PDF - instead you're likely writing doubled-up gibberish (as far as Acrobat is concerned) to disk...

Comment: It's from formIO. We use formIO for all of our forms/submissions. The file content string is a response from formIO for the submission I requested. As far as what it is, if you read my question carefully, I don't know exactly what it is past that, and I uploaded a text document and pasted in the post in hopes that someone would recognize the encoding type.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work, please share the file again and post the URL.

Comment: Doh. FileIO only allows one download. Sorry. Edited.

Comment: Your example document includes '�' characters. Indicating that you do not have a valid unicode string. Which shouldn't be surprising, as pdf is not a text format. While it can contain ascii commands, it can also contain compressed binary and image content. You have to treat the data as a `byte[]` or `Stream`.

Comment: Instead of editing the question to say that it is solved, please accept your own answer as the solution, you may have to wait a short while after adding it.

Comment: It says I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer. That's why I put the edit there, in those 2 days, people know.

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: never read a file's contents as a string and then try to convert it back to raw bytes if you can avoid it. In this case, my contents were being read like so:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Simply switching it to:

`var content = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();`

And then:

`File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, content);`

Did the trick.

Comment: You need to `await` those async methods - otherwise the `var` keyword is hiding the fact that your `var content` is really a `Task<Byte[]>`, not a `Byte[]`. This is why I don't recommend using `var` unless you absolutely need to.